# Do spells end with the death of the caster?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

I was unimpressed by the performance of Dr Strange in *Avengers - Infinity War*. He seems to have underused his power as noted in other questions (and responses pointing out why he did not use them).

Having seen Loki stuck between two portals for 30 minutes in *Thor Ragnarok* I think that this could be yet another way for Dr Strange to get rid of Thanos: opening a portal and letting him travel to the other side without opening that other side.

**I was wondering, though, whether spells stop when the caster dies?** (this solution would buy at least some time for the Avengers / Guardians to work out a better plan).

Comment: I think the portal concept is more of a forceful push towards the end destination. And when reached they appear on the other side. I think once they are pushed, it cannot be stopped. (it is not a continued casting spell)

Comment: I don't think that you could trap Thanos in the portal.Like Doomsknight said, it isn't shown to be a continuous spell.And even if you could, he has the Space Stone, so he would escape any trap that you put him in. As for your question, a spell would end if the actual caster died because spells in MCU are cast by channeling energy from dimensions via sling ring. And you need a living person for that.

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88468/why-does-doctor-strange-not-bind-thanos-in-a-time-loop

Comment: Strange said something like "good luck breaking a dead wizard's spell" when the alien guy tried to take the Time Store before capturing him at the beginning of the movie, that would mean a "yes".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Doctor Strange himself spells do not end, but are in fact harder to break, when the casting wizard dies.

He says this to Ebony Maw, who threatens to kill him, after finding out about the protection spell on the Eye of Agamotto.

(Unfortunately I can't remember the exact quote at this time.)

Of course this could just be Strange trying to buy some time, as it appears Ebony Maw's powers come from a different place to his

Comment: Nice answer. That could also depend on the spell.

Comment: My impression was that that specific spell was setup this way (which makes sense, a spell that's meant to only enable ownership transfer based on the owners will that could be broken by killing the owner would be kind of pointless), not that spells work that way in general.