# Why didn't Dr.strange use the time stone when this event occurred?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, why didn't Dr. Strange use the time stone when Star-Lord woke up Thanos?

Did he forget?

Comment: There are a ton of questions asking about why Dr Strange allowed things to play out in the way that he did and they all get a variation of the same answer, that he saw millions of possibilities and only one for victory.  The inference is simply that Strange is following through whichever scenario leads to success...

Comment: see **https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88468/**

Answer (score 5):

At this moment, the Time Stone was hidden by Dr. Strange.

Moreover, we can assume that all the events which happened in this confrontation were a part of the only future over 14M where Thanos loses, and that might by why Strange didn't do anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

Previously in the movie, Dr. Strange used the time stone to view the possible outcomes in the future, discovering that there was only one way for the good guys to win.  We can therefore interpret that every decision Strange makes afterwards is necessary to directly influence the future into the correct course for them to win.

**Potential Future Spoilers:**

But, they didn't win, and Thanos obtained all of the infinity stones and killed half of the universe.  So how does this equal a win for the Avengers?  Well, in the comics the Avengers eventually get the Gauntlet from Thanos and undo the snap, restoring everyone that was killed.  According to Strange's actions, Tony being alive is important for this to happen and for the Avengers to win.

So, in conclusion, Dr. Strange allowed Starlord to wake up Thanos, Strange allowed Thanos to impale Tony, and Strange willingly gave up the stone, all in order to set up the end game.

Comment: The endgame indeed :)