# Why didn't Dr. Strange know about what's happening to the Infinity stones, or other realms?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

Dr Strange told Thor that he is monitoring all 9 realms in *Thor: Ragnarok*. So how come he didn't know what's happening at/to Nidavellir, Titan, or the Infinity Stones.

> **Strange:** My name is Doctor Stephen Strange, and I have some questions for you. Take a seat. Tea?
>
> **Thor:** I don't drink tea.
>
> **Strange:** What do you drink?
>
> **Thor:** Not tea.
>
> **Strange:** So, I keep a watch list of individuals and beings from other realms.

Comment: I definitely view that as a list of individuals and beings from other realms that he's looking for popping up on Earth, the planet he's sworn to protect.  Not that he can observe, or know about everything in the cosmos.

Comment: I concur that the quote doesn't match your assertion at all. He's got a list of "beings from other realms"; that's completely different from "is monitoring all 9 realms".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Someone not monitoring 9 realms, how that person get know who is who, who to monitor who not to? Imagine I am not following sports, but fan of Pete Sampras, how would I get to know who won recent wimbledon? Secondly a dwarf who can cast weapons as lethal as Stormbreaker lost entire population of his kind, still didnt ring a bell to Strange, how come?

Comment: @paul: Because he monitors Earth... using magic

Comment: From "I have a list of Foreigner" to "I monitor activity in this list of foreign country"

Comment: Titan is not one of the Nine realms - and only 3 of the infinity stones (Time, Space and Mind) were in the Nine Realms at the time (Reality *had* been, but had been taken to Knowhere)  Of course, since Dr Strange says "other realms" - not "the Nine Realms" - he may be including Titan or Knowhere in that "other".  So, your first 2 sentences **currently ask 2 different questions** - please revise.

Comment: @Chronocidal Names I have taken are just to quote examples. I meant all atrocious activities happening in 9 realms. If he could have figured out early, world/avengers wouldn't have gone through such mess/loss.

Comment: @paul Doctor Strange monitors *more* than just the Nine Realms - for example, the Dark Dimension.  Limiting your scope like that does the question a disservice.  This was one of the points that LightnessRacesinOrbit mentions (albeit briefly) in her responses.  I would advise changing that first sentence to just read "..he is monitoring *other* realms..", and then include the Nine Realms in your list of examples.  Much less confusion all around

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85657/discussion-on-question-by-paul-why-didnt-dr-strange-know-about-whats-happenin).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doctor Strange says that he monitors **individuals and beings** from other realms (planets such as Asgard or Knowhere, dimensions such as the Dark Dimension, etc), *not* the realms themselves.  So long as the individual is not the ruler of their realm/planet, he can presumably leave their own law enforcement to monitor them when they are nowhere near Earth.

As an equivalent:  the CIA or MI6 may monitor specific foreign nationals who have been flagged as potential threats, but they do not monitor everything going on in every country in the world - for one thing, they don't have the resources/manpower!  Doctor Strange is thus *highly* unlikely to be able to monitor more locations with less resources.

Also - Doctor Strange takes over from the Ancient One after the events of "Captain America: Civil War".  This means that, for example, during the events of "Avengers" or "Age of Ultron" he was still either in training, or had yet to travel to Kamar-Taj, and hardly in a position to intervene.

Answer (score 57):

> How come he didn't know what's happening at/to Nidavellir, Titan, Infinity Stones.

**Because he's not all-knowing.**

He can maintain a watchlist of **known** players but if he doesn't know about them, they won't be on the watchlist.

It's absolutely clear that Dr Strange does not know about Thanos since when Banner says "Thanos is coming."...Strange's reply is

> Who?

There's no indication that Strange has ever *heard* of Nidavellir or Titan and at the stage we join the action, Thanos has only just acquired a single stone so it's arguable he has no reason to be on Strange's mystical "*radar*".

Comment: The moment he got to know that he got into some serious business he should have started time loop.

Comment: @paul Regarding he should have started the time loop remark, here is a related question on that topic - https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/88469/33025

Answer (score 17):

**Strange is watching over the Earth. He is not actively monitoring the beings / realm.**

---

He never said he is monitoring all 9 realms. His exact lines were

> So, I keep a watch list of individuals and beings from other realms
>   that **may be a threat to this world**. Your adopted brother, Loki, is one
>   of these beings.

He did not care what Loki was doing to Asgard, not even sure if he was monitoring Asgard. He only intervened after Loki came to Earth.

Also I think that Loki was included in the list not because he was a Villan but because he tried to attack and conquer Earth. Thanos's affiliation to the attack is not known to anyone before Banner told them. Since Thanos has not attacked Earth (according to them at that point) he might not be on the list or he might not have known Thanos at all.

---

> So how come he didn't know what's happening at/to Nidavellir, Titan,
>   or the Infinity Stones.

1. Nidavellir was a peaceful planet. It was no direct threat to Earth. It is possible that no one on Strange's list was on that planet and so he was not monitoring it.
2. Titan was assumed as a dead planet with no life. Why would anyone monitor it?
3. The Infinity Stones were in many hands before and the only stones that affects the people of Earth were the ones on the Earth. The Power stone was with Nova core, Ether will the collector, Mind stone with Vision, Time stone with Strange and Space stone with the Asgardians. The infinty stone were with people who will not use it to destroy life / attack Earth. So Strange will be less concerned about it than the beings such as Dormamu.